# How to quickly work a linechart created with jfreechart

Tags: java, swt, jfreechart

Currently I use jfreechart through swt.

The current problem is tens of thousands of files 
(currently between 10,000 and 20,000, up to 100,000 later)

currently use DefaultXYDataset and XYLineAndShapeRenderer to load data after opening a file.

There's a problem.

1. The chart on the screen is not immediate (within seconds).
   Work with setchart in the current file open listener.
2. When resizing the shell, there is a delay in drawing the chart. 
   This causes the program to run slowly.
3. The jfreechart zoom function and mouse drag events are slow.

question

1. Is there a quick way to draw when redrawing a new data chart in chartcomposite?
2. Essentially, is XYLineAndShapeRenderer not good at rendering tens of thousands of data?
   If so, what is the best method?
3. There is a slight speedup using fastscatterplot but I want the line to be a line rather than a dot.
   Is there a way to line fastscatterplot?

Here is my code. 
Are there speed issues in your current code?

```
public void open() {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(800, 600);
    shell.setText("SWT Application");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    ...(setting widget and layout)

    chart = createChart(createDataset());
    frame = new ChartComposite(shell, SWT.NONE, chart, true);
    frame.setDisplayToolTips(false);
    GridData data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
    data.widthHint = 600;
    data.heightHint = 366;
        frame.setLayoutData(data);

    MenuItem mntmOpen = new MenuItem(menu_1, SWT.NONE);
    mntmOpen.setText("Open");
    mntmOpen.addListener(SWT.Selection, event -> {

    ...(parsing data)

        //using DefaultXYDataset and XYLineAndShapeRenderer 
        chart = createChart(createDDataset(xDataArray1,yDataArray1));

        frame.setChart(chart); // Is this the wrong way to draw a new chart?

        shell.open();
    });


private JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset){
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
            "", "x", "y", dataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false, false);

    XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, false);

    int seriesCount = plot.getSeriesCount();
      for (int i = 0; i < seriesCount; i++) {
        plot.getRenderer().setSeriesStroke(i, new BasicStroke(0));
      }

    ...(set gridline and plot color)
    ...(set domain&range axis)

    return chart;
}
```

Comment: *Are there speed issues in your current code?* 1. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour is more suitable for this type of task. 2. This is not our code.

Comment: thank you for ur comment. gl

Comment: These [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20swingworker) use a worker thread; I don't know the SWT equivalent.

Comment: I solved the problem. ChartComposite is slow when the dataset renders a large chart. Using SWT-AWT to launch a chart will improve speed.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).